# SNS SQS fanout architecture

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

Looking at [the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToSQS.html) for this pattern it says

> The Amazon SQS message contains the subject and message that were published to the topic along with metadata about the message in a JSON document

So when I publish to an SNS topic, the only properties that are forwarded are the subject of the notification, and the default parameter? Does this mean if I want to send json to my queues I have to stringify it and set it as the default parameter of the notification?

Comment: I can't find a way to ask this without it sounding rude, so I apologize in advance: what else would you expect to be able do?

Comment: default implies that I want to change the message sent to any service not explicitly configured. I want so only change the message I send to SQS. I've actually found the solution, check it out below!

Comment: Funny, I understood your question but misinterpreted your motivation.  I assumed that you were only sending to SQS, so using "default" was a given/not an issue... and so I thought what you were actually asking was "do I *have to* stringify it to JSON?"  Hence, "what else would you expect to be able to do?"  :)  +1 for finding your own answer and sharing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check out the [examples section of the SNS docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_Publish.html#API_Publish_Examples) you can see there are options to specify messages to email, https, etc including sqs. If you want to send queue specific information on a notification then you can put it in there and it will overwrite the default parameter. An example in node

```
sns.publish({
  TopicArn: topicArn,
  MessageStructure: 'json',
  Message: JSON.stringify({
    default: JSON.stringify(defaultMessageJson),
    sqs: JSON.stringify(sqsMessageJson)
  })
})
```